# C# Exception when window restored via taskbar click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main form, `frmMain`. Everything is fine but whenever I minimize this window and then restore it clicking on taskbar,the  exception is thrown.

Exception:

> Rectangle '{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}' cannot have a width or height
>   equal to 0.

is thrown at `Program.cs` on line

```
Application.Run(new frmMain());
```

As i m new in C# I m not being able to solve this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I haven't use custom paintings, also havent used anything to deal with windows height or width programatically

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: Do you have any custom code in your form that deals with the Rectangle class?

Comment: Regarding edit, positing relevant code and stacktrace would be helpful

Comment: Thanks guys I have found the  culprit. THe custom panel control was causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using custom painting, which uses some kind of `LinearGradientBrush` or something like that. That would throw `ArgumentException` saying

> Rectangle '{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}' cannot have a width or height
>   equal to 0.

For instance following code will reproduce the problem.

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
var b = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(r, Color.AliceBlue, Color.AntiqueWhite, 90);
```

So you need to make sure your rectangle's `Size` is not empty(i.e Height and Width not equal to zero).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you store your form position somewhere so when run again you can restore your position. Store on `FormClosing` event and read it only once.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid further attention, and thinking would be helpful if someone find this post.

The culprit was custom control, which had dock property to "fill". I removed this control and instead used another default control and the problem is gone.

Thanks everyone for the help.